# I want to create NanoString Set From Csv

Tags: r

I cannot go past this error:

> "Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
> In addition: Warning message:
> In file(file, "rt") :
> cannot open file 'C:/Users/felix/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/NanoStringDiff/extdata/raw_data_combined.csv': No such file or directory

I tried using this code:

```
NanoStringData = createNanoStringSetFromCsv(path, header = T,designs)
```

and i got the error i stated previouly

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll get a better response if you [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This means: include all the relevant code, libraries and example data, as plain text. In this case it seems that you have a variable `path` pointing to a file which does not exist?

Comment: what does `file.exists(path)` return? TRUE or FALSE

Comment: It returns a TRUE